# Is it possible to use hoverIntent with D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, hoverintent

I am trying to use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) with D3. Now, hoverIntent works just like [jQuery's hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Originally, I created mouseOver-events in D3 like this:

```
nodes
  .on("mouseover", highlightNode)
  .on("mouseout", unhighlightNode)
```

However, using "hoverIntent" (or "hover") in `on` is not possible, because they are pseudo-events.

And while D3 selectors seem to act just like jQuery selectors, executing something like `nodes.hover(highlightNode, unhighlightNode)` is not possible. It *is* possible to replace `hover` by binding "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events to the respective handlers, but I do not see how to replace `hoverIntent` in a similar fashion.

Is there a way to do decompose `hoverIntent` into events that can be bound using `on`? Or is there a way to convert D3 selections into jQuery selections?

Comment: You could call a function on each element of the selection using `.each()` where `this` will be the current element. You can use that to install the JQuery handler.

Comment: It would be nice to get a full solution of this with plain javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion by Lars Kotthoff, I was able to attach the `hoverIntent` handler.

```
nodes.each (d, i) ->
  $(this).hoverIntent (-> highlightNode(d, i)), (-> unhighlightNode(d, i))
```

(code in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/))

Naturally, `highlightNode` and `unhighlightNode` expect D3 elements, not the DOM element. D3's `each` function on selections provides both, the D3 elelent (in `d`) as well as the DOM element (bound to `this`).

I use `this` to select the DOM element and call `hoverIntent` on it. The handlers for "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" are anonymous functions that call the existing handlers `highlightNode` and `unhighlightNode` with the respective D3 elements `d`.

Comment: .each(function (d, i) { $(this).hoverIntent(function() { console.log('hi'); }, function() { console.log('bye'); }) }); for completeness.